# AngularJs2 get the find() method in component for element

Tags: angular, event-handling, find, components

Here I want to check, if user click outside of my "DropdownComponent" element than hide some data. But "this.templateRef.nativeElement.find" I am not able to get "find()" method in angularJS2.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Output, HostListener } from '@angular/core';    
export class DropdownComponent{
showValue = true;

constructor(private templateRef: ElementRef) {
};

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(kbdEvent: any) {
    console.log("---"+ kbdEvent);
    var isClickedElementChildOfDropdownComponent = this.templateRef.nativeElement.find(kbdEvent.target).length > 0;

    if(isClickedElementChildOfDropdownComponent ) {
        return;
    }

    this.showValue = false;
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you could use, `querySelectorAll` querySelectorAll(this.templateRef.nativeElement, 'copy-me')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `contains`,

```ts
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(kbdEvent: any) {

    var isClickOutside = !this.templateRef.nativeElement.contains(kbdEvent.target);

    if(isClickOutside) {
        return;
    }

    this.showValue = false;
}
```